# Append template from a XSLT into another XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am working in Visual Studio 2012 with C#.
I have two xslt files.
One has a few templates.
Another has some nodes defined there.
All i want is to build a function in C# using which i pass the template name. Using that name it search in the one xslt and if there is a template with the given name, it copies it over into the second xslt.

F("GetMonth") should result as following:

```
XSLT1:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="GetMonth">
  <xsl:param name="Month"/>
  <xsl:param name="PutCall"/>
  <xsl:value-of select ="'A'"/>
</xsl:template>

XSLT2:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <DocumentElement>
 // Some Code written
  </DocumentElement>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Resultant XSLT2:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="GetMonth">
  <xsl:param name="Month"/>
  <xsl:param name="PutCall"/>
  <xsl:value-of select ="'A'"/>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <DocumentElement>
     // Some Tags defined here
    </DocumentElement>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My attempt:

```
XmlDocument xslDoc1 = new XmlDocument();
XmlDocument xslDoc2 = new XmlDocument();
xslDoc1.Load("XSLT1.xslt");
xslDoc2.Load("XSLT2.xslt");

XmlNamespaceManager nsMg1r = new XmlNamespaceManager(xslDoc1.NameTable);
nsMgr1.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");

XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr2 = new XmlNamespaceManager(xslDoc2.NameTable);
nsMgr2.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");

XmlNodeList template = (XmlNodeList)xslDoc.SelectNodes("/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template[@name = templateName]", nsMgr);
if(template != null)
{
 // What code should be written here???
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Just a quick observation: The XSLT import/include directives might address your needs without having to do programmed editing of stylesheets.

Comment: how exactly? please give me an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string templateName = "GetMonth";

XmlNode template = xslDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template[@name = '{0}']", templateName), nsMgr);

if (template != null)
{
  // will append the template as last child of xsl:stylesheet
  xslDoc2.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xslDoc2.ImportNode(template, true));
  // as alternative to insert as the first child use
  // xslDoc2.DocumentElement.InsertBefore(xslDoc2.ImportNode(template, true), xslDoc2.DocumentElement.FirstChild);
  // now Save
  xslDoc2.Save("XSLT2.xslt");
}
```

Comment: What happens, do you get an error, if so, which one? Or is the result not as wanted? Then explain which result you get.

Comment: The result is not what i want. It is not appending the Template in the existing xslt file.

Comment: Have you called `xslDoc2.Save("XSLT2.xslt");` after adding the node? I have not shown that because I felt it is obvious but I will edit and add that call.